# Getting statsmodel RollingOLS results summary information

Tags: python, statistics, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am running rolling regressions using the RollingOLS function on statsmodels.api, and wondering if its possible to get the summary statistics (betas, r^2, etc.) out for each regression done in the rolling regression.

Using a single OLS regression, you can get the summary information like such,

```
X_opt  = X[:, [0,1,2,3]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog= y, exog= X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()


                          OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.951
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.948
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     296.0
Date:                Wed, 08 Aug 2018   Prob (F-statistic):           4.53e-30
Time:                        00:46:48   Log-Likelihood:                -525.39
No. Observations:                  50   AIC:                             1059.
Df Residuals:                      46   BIC:                             1066.
Df Model:                           3                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const       5.012e+04   6572.353      7.626      0.000    3.69e+04    6.34e+04
x1             0.8057      0.045     17.846      0.000       0.715       0.897
x2            -0.0268      0.051     -0.526      0.602      -0.130       0.076
x3             0.0272      0.016      1.655      0.105      -0.006       0.060
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       14.838   Durbin-Watson:                   1.282
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.001   Jarque-Bera (JB):               21.442
Skew:                          -0.949   Prob(JB):                     2.21e-05
Kurtosis:                       5.586   Cond. No.                     1.40e+06
==============================================================================
```

is there a way to get this information for the regression run on each window for a rolling regression?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take a look at this and ask again. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to generate a table for each sliding window. However, we could use build in functions to get access to params, tvalues, pvalues, and so on.

```
rols = RollingOLS(y, x, window)
rres = rols.fit()
rres.params  # gives table of coefficients for each window
rres.tvalues # gives table of t-values for each window
rres.pvalues # gives table of p-values for each window
```

Refer to https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingRegressionResults.html#statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingRegressionResults
for more functions we can use.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34710802)